# Mikro ORM : What is the best way to upsert a collection

Tags: mikro-orm

In the following scenario a whole `SalesOrder` entity is passed in to the server
items collection of sales order entity can have new items, removed items and updated items.
just persisting the `SalesOrder` don't work (wont remove or update)
this is the way i got it to work. is there a better way? or an I missing something?

```
async save(@Body() item: SalesOrder) {

let result: SalesOrder;
result = await em.getRepository<SalesOrder>(SalesOrder).findOne(item.id);
item.items.forEach(k => k.salesOrder = item.id)
await this.em.getRepository(SalesOrderItem).nativeDelete({ salesOrder: item.id })
for (const [i, it] of item.items.entries()) {
    const x = em.getRepository(SalesOrderItem).create({ ...it })
    await em.persistAndFlush(x)
}
wrap(result).assign({ ...item, items: null }, {})

await em.getRepository(SalesOrder).persistAndFlush(result);
await em.flush()
}
```

```
@Entity()
export class SalesOrder extends BaseEntity {
    @PrimaryKey( )
    id: number;

    @OneToMany(i => SalesOrderItem, t => t.salesOrder, { eager: true, cascade: [Cascade.ALL] })
    items = new Collection<SalesOrderItem>(this); 
}

@Entity()
export class SalesOrderItem extends BaseEntity {

    @ManyToOne({ entity: () => InventoryItem, eager: true, primary: true })
    item: IdentifiedReference<InventoryItem>;

    @Property({ type: JsonType, columnType: 'jsonb', nullable: true })
    configuration?: SalesOrderItem[]

    @ManyToOne({ entity: () => SalesOrder, hidden: true, primary: true })
    salesOrder: IdentifiedReference<SalesOrder>;

    @Property({ nullable: false })
    qty: number;

    @Property({ nullable: false })
    unitPrice: number;

    [PrimaryKeyType]: [string, string]
}
```